# Does default constructor have to be provided if there are no meaningful values?

Tags: c++, default-constructor

The default constructor is used automatically whenever an object is default or
value initialized. So it is convenient having a default constructor.

But if there are no meaningful default values for a class,

- should the class still have to provide a default constructor?
- is there any bad influence if no default constructor is provided?

For example, a person should have a name, an empty string is not a meaningful name:

```
#include <string>

class Person {
public:
    Person() : name("") {}  // Does it have to be supplied?
    explicit Person(const std::string &n) : name(n) {}
private:
    std::string name;
};
```

Comment: If you consider your class `default-constructed` as incomplete and unusable then don't provide a default-constructor.

Answer (score 2):

> But if there are no meaningful default values for a class, should the class still have to provide a default constructor?

Generally-speaking, no. If your objects should not be initialised into an invalid state then the constructor must provide the means for creating valid objects, which means they must take arguments.

You *might* need to provide a default constructor:

- If you're using a serialization/deserialization framework or other runtime service which creates objects by itself and then sets fields later (e.g. an ORM).
- If you're using `std::map` the value-type needs a default-constructor
- If you're creating simple DTO objects where it's okay for the object to exist in an invalid state.

> is there any bad influence if no default constructor is provided?

If you mean "no program-defined parameterless constructor", then the compiler will create one for you, this might be undesired, so you must use the `= delete` modifier to ensure the compiler does not create the default constructor.

As for the case when your objects have no default nor parameterless constructor you might find some containers in the STL might not work with your class.

Comment: Note that the `delete` modifier is C++11 (there are still compilers out there that don't support it :).

Comment: Thanks for the answers, about the second question, I mean only provide constructors with parameters. For example, only provide the constructor  `explicit Person(const std::string &n) : name(n) {}` in the code (so that there is no compiler synthesized default ctor).